# csv file having column not oriented properly

Tags: python

I have a csv file which is as following

```
1,'Man','Loves',
'Japan'
2,'Woman','Loves','Japan'
3,'Man','Loves,'Japan'
4,'Man','Loves',
'Japan'
5,'Man','Loves','Taiwan'
```

As we can see the csv file record moves to the next line in some cases . How can i correct it and make sure file is like this.

```
  1,'Man','Loves','Japan'
  2,'Woman','Loves','Japan'
  3,'Man','Loves,'Japan'
  4,'Man','Loves','Japan'
  5,'Man','Loves','Taiwan'
```

Updated question

```
x = re.findall(r.'Time (.*?);',data,re.DOTALL)
```

### This pull data between word 'Time' and ';'.This is further saved to csv file.

Ideally the sting between 'Time' and ';' should be on same line but in some cases it on different lines. I think this causes problem. I tried using rstrip but it didn't help. The csv file was still same.

The code is on different machine(production) so  I typed what I could.

Comment: Could you show the actual code generating this CSV file?

Comment: @alecxe updated question

Comment: What do you want?  A solution to reading the mangled data or a solution to fix writing that data?

Comment: @wallyk I want the line not to be split and the one which saves my csv files.

Comment: How about just editing the file?

Comment: I did that but I like to be automatic.

Comment: Why is there `Time` in the regex and not in the example? Do valid lines always start with a number? That might be a good way to start: 1) read line, split into fields; 2) if line does not start with a number, add field(s) to previous record; 3) if line does start with a number, start new record. Another question would be how the "broken" CSV is created and maybe fix this first.

Comment: @Jasper the program searches for data between 'Time' and ';' and save it to csv. so whatver result we get from regex we save to file.